# How to un-break which.min on tibbles

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

/R-newb.
My which.min call works fine on a column of my dataframe but on loading dplyr which.min no longer works. Is it because the df is now a tibble? Any workaround?

```
> which.min(Analytic_traces_raw[,1]) #********************WORKS FINE HERE**
[1] 1
> library(dplyr)

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
    filter, lag
The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

> which.min(Analytic_traces_raw[,1]) #*********************NOW IT'S BROKEN**
Error in which.min(Analytic_traces_raw[, 1]) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

> head(Analytic_traces_raw[,1]) #**TYPE IS DBL, BUT TIBBLE TROUBLE**?
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  `t_Pur23Mar18_TP7-24`
                  <dbl>
1              0.000417
2              0.00375 
3              0.00708 
4              0.0104  
5              0.0138  
6              0.0171
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not `which.min` that "broke" it's that tibbles "broke" the default behavior in R. Normally, for data frames, `Analytic_traces_raw[,1]` will drop dimensions and become a vector. tibbles changed that behavior, so R functions that expect "normal" behavior will break. Try `Analytic_traces_raw[[1]]`:

```
library(dplyr)
which.min(mtcars[,1])
[1] 15
> mtcars_tbl <- as_tibble(mtcars)
> which.min(mtcars_tbl[,1])
Error in which.min(mtcars_tbl[, 1]) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
> which.min(mtcars_tbl[[1]])
[1] 15
```

Comment: [[1]] notation works. Explicit coercion didn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problems like this can be fixed by specifying the package name before the command, e.g.

```
raster::which.min(Analytic_traces_raw[,1])
```

(or replace the package name if you're actually using a `which.min` that's different than the ones in `dplyr` or `raster`). Here is an example (although not one that gives different results):

```
> data(iris)
> apply(iris, 2, raster::which.max)
$Sepal.Length
[1] 132

$Sepal.Width
[1] 16

$Petal.Length
[1] 119

$Petal.Width
[1] 101

$Species
integer(0)

> apply(iris, 2, base::which.max)
$Sepal.Length
[1] 132

$Sepal.Width
[1] 16

$Petal.Length
[1] 119

$Petal.Width
[1] 101

$Species
integer(0)
```